# Find the probability distribution of $Z = X + Y$

Tags: probability

> Let $ X ∼ Geom (p)$ and $Y ∼ U (0, 1, . . . , n)$ be random variables. Find the probability distribution of $Z = X + Y$ .

What I did so far:

$$ P(X+Y=k) $$
$$ = \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)*P(Y=y) $$
$$ = \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)*\frac{1}{1+n} $$

$X$ and $Y$ may be dependent or not. Any clues?

Comment: I have two questions for you: 1) do you know if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and if not: 2) do you know the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$? If you can't answer either of these, it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: I don't have anything else then what I provided. =\

Comment: In my experience, 99% of the time, when question writers write a question like this, they mean for the random variables to be independent. I would try operating on that assumption. If this is for a class, you should ask your professor for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this should work:

Let $q=1-p$

\begin{eqnarray*}
  P(X+Y=m) &=& \sum_{k=1}^m P(X=k\cap Y=m-k) \\
   &=& \sum_{k=1}^m P(X=k)P(Y=m-k) \\
   &=& \sum_{k=1}^m q^{k-1}p{1\over n+1} \\
   &=& {p\over n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q^k  \\
   &=&  {p\over n+1}{1-q^m\over 1-q}\\
   &=&  {1-q^m\over n+1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The bounds of your second to last summation should be from $k=\max(1,m-n)$ to $m$, because the uniform random variable can only be between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: Yeah, true........